# Creating a single hyperlink from 2 mysql table entries using php

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I have a mysql table containing the values for 'display' and 'link'.

I'd like to pull these into a php file that displays the 'display' value which hyperlinks to the 'link' value

I have already connected to the database and selected the appropriate rows to display, but I'm at a loss on how to create the php for this..

As you can probably tell, I'm a complete noob so simplicity is appreciated in any answers.. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like so?

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo '<a href="'.$row["link"].'">'.$row["display"].'</a>';
```

Answer (score 2):

One addition to the previous posters code. You'll want to escape the values before outputting them **to prevent html injection attacks** (and general wonkiness if special characters are in the links or titles).

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($row["link"]_.'">'. htmlspecialchars($row["display"]).'</a>';
```